# How do you determine the standard deviation, based only on n (sample size)

Tags: binomial-distribution

I'm not sure I'm asking the question exactly right, but here's the situation. I'm standing in line at Burger King with a friend, and he looks around & says "only nine people in here voted." When pressed, he says, based on a 47% turnout and a sample of 20 people, 9 people voted.
So there are many issues here, first of all being that "people in BK on Thursday for Lunch" isn't a random sample.
But ignore that, for now. I feel confident there's a way to say "assuming a normal distribution (and does that even apply to a binary choice, would it be poisson?), and assuming this is in fact a random sample, the chances that (say a sample s of 2) less than seven or more than 11 people voted is 32% (outside one std. deviation). But how can I calculate/estimate the "s" to make those brackets based on a population only?

Background, I've had a stats class in engineering & did well, so I can get a bit into the weeds, and if you point me to the right name for this type of analysis I can probably take it home.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each person is voting or not voting independently, your random variable $X$, the number of people voting, has a binomial distribution with $n=20$ a success probability of $p=0.47$.

$$P(X=k) = \binom{n}{k}(p)^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

The mean of this distribution is $np = 9.4$, and the variance is $np(1-p)$, so the standard deviation is $\sqrt{np(1-p)} = 2.23$. To find the odds that less than 7 or more than 11 people voted, you could sum over the probabilities:

$$\sum_{k=1}^6 P(X=k) + \sum_{k=12}^{20} P(X=k)$$

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of "writing the question helped me solve it." Please feel free to edit my terminology if I get it wrong, but I feel confident that I understand the concepts.

These sorts of calculations are called a probability mass distribution. The key for realizing this is that the question you're asking isn't numerical, like salary or weight, but existential, yes or no. These are called "binomial distribution" -- as in, what's the likelihood that you get a certain number of hits, given a success probability, and a number of trials?

In our case, we can say, based on a "sample" of 20 and a 46.9% turnout, you 
can get the probability of any number of results. A decent calculator is here:
http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/binomial.aspx

To get to the standard "95% confidence" of most published polls, you can only say "I'm 95%  sure that between 5-13 people voted.

Comment: Editing my answer now

Comment: Hah, I think I'm waaaaay under the level of understanding on this site :)